# How to change the value of google sheet cell based on the specific value of another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am absolutely new to this and searching desperately to an answer to following task:

If the date of cell E2 has arrived cell H2 updates itself to "valid" and if date of cell F2 has arrived Cell H2 updates itself to "invalid"

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V6Ux7Ka6p60ZAxanm6eKPphF8KDLQItiArMYIX5UAz4/edit?usp=sharing)

I do not know how to do VBA or anything of that sort, which is why I looked into tools like "retool" but without any luck.

Maybe a formula will do they job.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete all that column you can use this formula in H2:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(E2:E="";"";IF(E2:E<=TODAY();IF(F2:F>=TODAY();"Valid";"Invalid");"Invalid")))
```

[image]

Comment: =IF(TODAY()=(E3);"valid";IF(TODAY()=(F3);"invalid";)) <= These seems to work but how do I express this state "invalid" in case none of both work? + how do I keep it valid once the date of E2 has passed but the date of F2 hasn't arrived.

Comment: You can express it like this: `=IF(AND(E2<=TODAY();F3>=TODAY());"Valid";"Invalid")` . It will say valid if both conditions are met

Comment: Martín you did it again! Thank you very much from the bottom of my heart!

Answer (score 0):

Try

=IF(isdate(E2);"valid";if(isdate(F2);"invalid";))

in Cell H2

If E2 is a date, it will return "valid"

If not, it will check F2

If F2 is a date, it will return "invalid"

Comment: =IF(TODAY()=(E3);"valid";IF(TODAY()=(F3);"invalid";))  <= These seems to work but how do I express this state "invalid" in case none of both work? + how do I keep it valid once the date of E2 has passed but the date of F2 hasn't arrived